# Segment violation ('core' generated) using GMP library

Tags: c++, gmp

how are you? I'm trying to learn to use the Multi Precision Library GMP on C++. There is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    mpf_set_default_prec (128);
    double a = 2., b = 3.;
    mpf_t x, y, z;

    mpf_set_d(x, a);
    mpf_set_d(y, b);

    mpf_div(z, x, y);

    gmp_printf("%.*Ff \n", 30, z);

    mpf_clear (x);
    mpf_clear (y);
    mpf_clear (z);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles correctly but in execution returns Segment violation ('core' generated). Where is the error?

Answer (score 1):

`mpf_t` is the C float type used by GMP. [As the documentation says](https://gmplib.org/manual/Initializing-Floats.html), "an `mpf_t` object must be initialized before storing the first value in it". So you should do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gmpxx.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    mpf_set_default_prec (128);
    double a = 2., b = 3.;
    mpf_t x, y, z;
    mpf_init(x);
    mpf_init(y);
    mpf_init(z);

    mpf_set_d(x, a);
    mpf_set_d(y, b);

    mpf_div(z, x, y);

    gmp_printf("%.*Ff \n", 30, z);

    mpf_clear (x);
    mpf_clear (y);
    mpf_clear (z);

    return 0;
}
```

However, if you are using C++ you may consider using the [C++ interface](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html) of the library, which would save you the init and clear calls.